# How to find all points away from some polygon?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

What I need is to find all points away from rectangle for 10km. Points geometry is the_geom1, rectangles (polygon) geometry is the_geom2. SRID of them is 4258.

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1,table2 
WHERE ST_DWithin(table1.the_geom1,table2.the_geom2,10000) 
      and table1.gid=2;
```

But the result is not Ok.  I get way too many results (everything is returned).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The above should work. Are you using geometry or geography? Did you notice any pattern? Can you post some sample data (here or elsewhere) to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I am using geometry for example: ("0103000020A210000001000000050000005C6F7D6D3E6A2940927572284B67464011C5BC925A4B2940B8A238CA38DA464081254FE8D4242D40302212E575E046407681E4F852342D40F48EB143576D46405C6F7D6D3E6A2940927572284B674640")
 How to express this 10km???? 
What I got by query above is result of 10000 rows what is exactly the number of rows of table2.
If I use st_contains intead of st_dwithin to see what points are within the polygon with gid=2 I got the right result. Now I need to expand area around polygon for 10km.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work.  The big issue may be as described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/how-do-i-use-st-dwithin-with-meters which discusses unit conversion issues.

You may have an issue with unit selection or configuration.

If you are telling it, for example, that the geometries must be within 10000 miles, you would get just about everywhere.  Even 10000km would likely return everything on the same continent.